# Javascript console.log weird behavior on browser console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, firefox

If i run the following code on chrome or firefox directly into the console, on the **first** log  the value of value2 is 0 in the inlined representation, but if I expand the representation to check the whole object, it is showed as 17. Is this a multi browser bug or I am missing something with javascript here? The reason I am asking this question here is because this behaviour is happening across different browsers, which makes me think there is some kind of catch on the language or the function that I am not aware of.

Actual code:

```
action = new Object();
action.value1 = 17;
action.value2 = 0;

console.log(action);
action.value2 = action.value1;
console.log(action);
```

Tested on MacOS Catalina with the latest version of both browsers.

EDIT-----------------

The problem is the **first** console.log prints value2 being 0 but when I expand the object details it is showed as 17. I attached a print to clarify the question.

[PRINT OF THE CONSOLE RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWb1G.png)

I would expect the result to be 0 on the value2 of the first output even with the expanded view.

Comment: You might need to clarify this if the answer below doesn't help. Seems like you don't understand what should be happening with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` has different inner working between chrome, firefox, nodejs, and other javascript engine.

In your screenshot, the browser does 2 things:

1. prints the short preview of the `action` object
2. prints the expandable reference of the `action` object

The short preview is a readable version snapshot of the object at the time `console.log` is called

The expendable reference only prints an expand icon at the time `console.log` is called.
When expanded, chrome will fetch the CURRENT value the object referenced by that expendable reference and print it. It doesn't print the value when `console.log` is called

Since the value when the `console.log` is called (`{value1: 17, value2: 0}`), and the current value (`{value1: 17, value2: 17}`) is different, it prints different thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a new change to the object then I expanded the second log (that was already printed beforehand) and I could verify what you explained.